# problems with mysql for ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

ah...it is not easy to get started ruby on rails to me..

I am trying to use mysql for ruby on rails development.

When I execute "gem install mysql", I get following error.

error: while generating documentation for mysql-2.8.3-x86-mswin32...message: unhandled special: special: type=17...bla bla...

how do I install mysql for ruby on rails!??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows and want to avoid mysql issues, just use v 2.1.2, just before they removed the mysql connector and put it into the mysql gem. It's better like that, but I ran into MANY issues installing this on the Windows XP machine at my work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your version of gems is the latest.

You should be able to update it using:

```
gem update --system
```

Going by your error it failed to generate the documentation for the Gem, though it could have installed it as it was. Firstly check to see if it did install, use:

```
gem list --local
```

And check to see if the MySQL driver is in the list already.

If it isn't the make sure you're installing the correct version of the driver, either mswin32, or ruby should do.

Comment: when I exeucte gem update --system, it displays
"Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update"

Answer (score 0):

That's an error concerning rdoc generation. If you execute the following command you'll get no error:

```
gem install --no-rdoc mysql
```

I believe there are some problems generating rdoc for the Japanese localized version of the docs. Anyway, the mysql gem gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install the MySQL gem

either install the MySQL in ruby file where all gems are install or you can follow the path:

**C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems**

execute the below command:

**gem install  MySQL**

hope this helps you!